# SharePoint add-ins updates

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, list-view

I have a SharePoint hosted add-in, whenever I try to update any of the below items, it doesn't reflect except if I redoply the add-in. which will results in data loss.

List of changes:

1. Adding data to list in list element.xml.
2. Creating new list views.
3. Changing the code in list schema.
4. Customizing list forms (new ,
   edit and display)

**Questions**

do I have to redoply for editing any of the above? what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

In order to update your app without losing data, you have to use the [update process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179904.aspx).  Simply update the app version in the app manifest to a higher version, and you will be able to update your app without losing existing data.

I have ran into some issues with having items in the list's element.xml file being inserted again, so watch out for that.